# Glmnet lasso logistic regression - Correct form of specifying lambda for final predictions?

Tags: r, glmnet

I would like to make sure that I am using the prediction method here correctly; maybe I am misinterpreting the parameter "s" here!? My intent is to use the best lambda obtained from cross validation to make my final predictions on a holdout dataset.

```
# set alpha to 1 for lasso
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x = mat, y = class, family = "binomial", alpha = 1, nfolds = 10)

val.m <- as.matrix(val.df[, -match(c("Id", "class"), names(val.df))])
preds <- predict(cv.fit, val.m, type="response", s = cv.lasso.fit$lambda.min)
```

It would be nice if someone could give me reassurance.

Comment: You're using it right, the `s =` specifies the lambda value.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered, because the average cross validation error rate does not match my results on the validation set at all. On the validation set, the model always predicts the -1 class. Its strange, but good to know that it is not due to an error in these commands.